# Limit query to current day

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I'm using these args with the intention of showing posts from a custom post type (clothing):

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'type',
            'value'   => 'shoes',
            'type'    => 'char',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    ),
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'clothing'
);
```

This works fine, but what I want to do is limit the query to posts that were created today only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to use [`date_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). You could do something like this.

```
'date_query'    => array(
    'column'  => 'post_date',
    'after'   => '- 1 days'
)
```